# vue datatables, custumize number of columns to be displayed

Tags: vue.js, datatables, customization

```
npm install --save datatables.net-vue3 - to install datatable package

import DataTable from "datatables.net-vue3";
```

```html
<!-- checkboxes where we can select columns to be displayed -->
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="column" id="fieldId1" value="id" v-model="column"/>
  <label for="fieldId1">Id</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="column" id="fieldId2" value="title" v-model="column"/>
  <label for="fieldId2">Title</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="column" id="fieldId3" value="start" v-model="column"/>
  <label for="fieldId3">Start</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="column" id="fieldId4" value="date of arrival" v-model="column"/>
  <label for="fieldId4">Date of arrival</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="column" id="fieldId5" value="status" v-model="column"/>
  <label for="fieldId5">Status</label>
</div>
```

```html
<DataTable :data="data" class="display table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Date of arrival</th>    
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</DataTable>
```

only columns selected from checkboxes should be displayed in table.

Comment: Hi, please make an effort regarding your question. Provide some context, a better written expected result or a [repro]. As of right now, it's pretty cryptic what you want to achieve. Is it a CSS issue? Some bug? Feel free to provide a screenshot/drawing or anything relevant.

Comment: I need a datatable  in vuejs which can be customizable. my requirement is when I select a group of columns from checkbox, only selected checkbox columns should be displayed.